# Django user.is_authenticated works in views but not templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a view and that logs in a user:

```
def login_user(request):
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))

username = password = ''
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            c.update(user(request))
            return redirect('/module/')
        else:
            return redirect('/inactive/')
    else:
        return redirect('/failure/')

return render_to_response('core/auth.html',c)
```

This correctly logs in a user, as i can then access the django admin page if I am on my superuser.

After logging in and being redirected I would like to display the username on the screen, currently I am using

```
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
          {% else %}
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
          {% endif %}
```

But it seems to always believe the user is not logged in. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here are my template context processors

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
 "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
 "django.core.context_processors.debug",
 "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
 "django.core.context_processors.media",
 "django.core.context_processors.static",
 "django.core.context_processors.tz",
 "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
 "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Comment: What have you got in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ? You will need `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` to have access to `{{ user }}` and / or `django.core.context_processors.request` to have access to `{{ request }}` (and by extension `{{ request.user }}`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried sending a RequestContext object to your template ?

```
return render_to_response('core/auth.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I've added in the RequestContext and it gives me the error: global name 'RequestContext' is not defined

Comment: ...so import it! `django.template.RequestContext` eg `from django.template import RequestContext`

Comment: Context processors don't apply unless you render with a RequestContext. Sinc Django 1.3, it's preferable to use [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead of [`django.shortcuts.render_to_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), because it forces you to always use one.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the shortcut function [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) to finish your view:

This will allow you to pass the `request` object to the template:

```
return render(request, 'core/auth.html', c)
```